# Catch Capslock press in Cocoa application

Tags: macos, cocoa, event-handling, keyboard-shortcuts

I’m working on an application that uses the great [MASShortcut repository](https://github.com/shpakovski/MASShortcut) by Shpakovski. I reference this to ask if there is a way to register a shortcut for Capslock in the same way that Shpakovski does in his repository?

It seems that I can’t register 0xffff ([Key Codes](http://manytricks.com/keycodes/) shows this as Capslock) as a valid shortcut. Even if I combine it with the modifier keys. I also want to catch the press before it toggles the system’s Capslock functionality.

I’m aware that I could listen to all keystrokes and just catch the Capslock when it occurs but I want to avoid this behaviour since I feel it’s potentially insecure and will also decrease the overall system performance.

Edit: I already took a look at some working C++ / C# libraries for Windows which implement this feature. They seem to override the system’s Capslock flag continuously which I found pretty odd. I’m basically having 2 problems here:

**1. How to catch the Capslock press without having a keystroke listener all the time**

**2. How to do so without triggering the system’s Capslock functionality.**

Answer (score 1):

One possibility could be to overwrite `sendEvent:` in your `NSApplication` `delegate`. From [Apples documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/applicationkit/classes/nsapplication_class/reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSApplication/sendEvent%3a):

> You rarely invoke sendEvent: directly, although you might want to
>   override this method to perform some action on every event. sendEvent:
>   messages are sent from the main event loop (the run method).
>   sendEvent: is the method that dispatches events to the appropriate
>   responders—NSApp handles application events, the NSWindow object
>   indicated in the event record handles window-related events, and mouse
>   and key events are forwarded to the appropriate NSWindow object for
>   further dispatching.

You could evaluate if the current event has the modifier key pressed and act upon that.

Edit:

For background processing [Quartz event taps](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Reference/QuartzEventServicesRef/Reference/reference.html) can be used. If that leads to a rejection, I don't know.

Comment: If I do this, will I be in danger of being rejected as a potential “key logger”, since I take a look on every keystroke? Will this also be called if the application is not on focus / in the background?

Comment: I don't think this will give problems regarding App Store. Subclassing sendEvent: per se is not forbidden. It will afaik only get called when your app has focus, though.

Comment: I’ve been rejected for a lot less than that. ;-) I need an implementation that works when the app is in the background though. :(

Comment: i have edited my answer regarding background processing using event taps.

Comment: Thanks Volker! I’ll take a closer look at it and if it works, I’ll accept your answer!